# How to validate all fields with the same function in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I need to do the following, but I couldn't find any example of similar form validation on the web:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function something(){
     if the value on the field who is calling this function == 2,4,6 or 8
     alert("This number is invalid")
     focus in this field. 
</script>

Field1 call something()
Field2 call something()
Field3 call something()
Field4 call something()
Field5 call something()
Field6 call something()
```

I've tried like this:

```
function validate()
        {
            valid = true;

            if ( document.form.field_name.value == "2" || document.form.field_name.value == "4" || document.form.field_name.value == "6" ||
           document.form.field_name.value == "8" ){
                alert ( "Invalid number." );
                valid = false;
                document.form.field_name.focus();

            }

            return valid;
        }
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
a)"Some text" <input type="text" name="aa" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return validate(aa)"><br>
```

But this way I would have to create a different function for every field. So how could I implement this?

Comment: Some of the solutions below require that you attach the validation to each form element, and some are scripts that you can run onsubmit before the form posts.  Both are good approaches.

Comment: The name of your field is a string, not an object or variable, so you need to **quote** it in your onkeypress attribute (`onkeypress="return validate('aa')"`) or use `this.name`: `onkeypress="return validate(this.name)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *bracket notation* instead of *dot notation* when collecting your form element, which allows you to use a variable:

```
function validate(field_name)
{
  var valid = true;
  var element = document.form[field_name];

  if (!element)
  {
    alert('A field named ' + field_name + ' cannot be found in your form!');
    return false;
  }

  var value = element.value;

  if (value == "2" ||  value == "4" || value == "6" || value == "8")
  {
    alert("Invalid number.");
    valid = false;
    element.focus();
  }

  return valid;
}
```

Then you'd just call `validate` with the name of the field you want to validate.

**Resources:**

- [Dot Notation and Square Bracket Notation in JavaScript](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)

Comment: It says the following in IE:  'value' is null or not a object on the 5º line in your code. I edited the question to show how I'm calling the function.

Comment: Is your form actually named `form`? Does the field name you are passing into `validate` exist?

Comment: My form name is actually called 'questionario', I changed that. Also, as you can see in my question ( that I edited ) I'm calling the function passing the 'aa' field from inside the 'aa' field.

Comment: @StudioWorks take a look at my comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
function validate()
    {
        var valid = true;

        var fields = ['list', 'of', 'unique', 'input', 'ids']; 

        for (inputid in fields) {
            field = document.getElementById(inputid);
            if ( field.value == "2" || field.value == "4" || field.value == "6" ||
       field.value == "8" ) {
                alert ( "Invalid number." );
                valid = false;
                field.focus();
                break;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parameterise your function, to pass the field (or its name in as an argument).

My example uses the prototype.js function $F, but you could do it equally well with jquery or (a bit more long-windedly) in native Javascript

```
function validate(field)
     {
            valid = true;
            value = $F(field);


            if ( value == "2" || value == "4" || value == "6" ||
           value == "8" ){
                alert ( "Invalid number." );
                valid = false;
                document.form.field_name.focus();

            }

            return valid;
        }

validate('field1');
validate('field2');
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com), and validate with something like this:

```
var valid = true;

$(".validateMe").each(function()
{
    var v = this.value;

    if(v == "2" || v=="4" || v=="6" || v=="8") {
        valid = false;

        // Exit for each
        return false;
    } 
});

if(!valid){
    alert("Invalid number.");
    $(this).focus();
}

return valid;
```

Each field would have to have the **"validateMe" CssClass**

Comment: Unless jQuery is already being used for something, this is really overkill.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript**
**1.** The if-else statements given on this website can be added to your validate function inside a loop that checks every field of the form.
http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/30/10-examples-of-basic-input-validation-in-javascript/

**2.** Still unclear then refer this great guide
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

**Using jQuery**

You can always try jQuery validation plugins
http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/22/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-functionality-validation-security-and-customisation/