# How can I validate multiple different form fields, I have searched and searched for a week

Tags: javascript, forms

How do I validate dd/mm/yyyy, numeric loan amount, alphabetic first, last name together. I am having trouble using this forum. Thanks for responding so fast!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
function validate(form){
    var message = 'Please fill in the following fields:\n\n\t';
    for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++){
        if(form.elements[i].value.length == 0){
            message+= form.elements[i].name.toUpperCase()+'\n\t'; 
        }
    } 
    message+= '\nOK   submit incomplete form';
    message+= '\nCANCEL  return to the form';
    message = confirm(message);
    if(!message){ return false };
    else{ return true };
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="loanform" action="processform.htm" method="get" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="15"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="15"><br>
        Birth Date: <input type="text" name="birthdate"  maxlength="8"><br>
        Loan Amount: <input type="text" name="loanamount"  maxlength="6" ><br>
        Years: <input type="text" name="years"  maxlength="2"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="reset" value="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>                                                                   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I did=above. Thank you for responding so quickly!Diane

Comment: **ProTip:** the last bit there could be `return confirm(message);`

Comment: Create a function that validate the form input fields as follows: (Note: use a “for-loop” here and check all of the fields as a field array in (a). Verify (b), (c) and (d) using the field name format).
a.       Check all fields for input and issue an alert for fields with no input.
b.      Verify that the Last Name and First Name form fields contain alphabetic characters only and are no longer than 15 characters each.
c.       Verify the format of the Loan Amount form field contains numeric content.
d.      Verify the date form field is in the format dd/mm/yyyy.
THANKS jfriend!!!!!!!!!

Comment: [Similar question here, would comment, but don't have the privilege][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3752139/958134

Comment: It works as it is but it isn't finished. Somehow I have to also validate for the above info not just if the fields are empty. So I have to add validation for dd/mm/yyyy format, numeric for loan amount and alphabetic for the first and last names. I can write the functions by themselves but I can't figure out how to include them into the required For Loop. For ......  If loan amount isNan then,,, if first and last name are Nan....

Comment: So confused as to how to validate everything I need all at once. Diane  DIADIL3@AOL.COM

Comment: OK none of my classmates better copy my code! Hey PAul, this is Diane. To all forum users: I am having trouble using this or telling if you responded. Did anyone give me a hint on how to validate for numeric, alphabetic and dd/mm/yyyy all at once? Thanks

Comment: I provided a fairly complete answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this.  It sets up a regular expression for each type of field and then makes a table that says which regular expression to use for which form element.  It uses the named form elements to access the individual values.

```
function validate(form) {
    var nameRE = /^[A-Za-z \.]+$/;
    var dateRE = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
    var amountRE = /^\$?[\d\.,]+$/;
    var yearsRE = /^\d+$/;

    var formItems = [
        {name: "firstname", re: nameRE, tag: "First Name"},
        {name: "lastname", re: nameRE, tag: "Last Name"},
        {name: "birthdate", re: dateRE, tag: "Birth Date", isDate: true},
        {name: "loanamount", re: amountRE, tag: "Loan Amount", min: 50000, max: 750000},
        {name: "years", re: yearsRE,  tag: "Years", min: 5, max: 30}
    ];

    var item, val, num, month, day, year, valid, matches, incomplete = false;
    var msg = 'Please fill in the following fields:\n\n\t';
    for (var i = 0; i < formItems.length; i++) {
        item = formItems[i];
        // strip leading or trailing whitespace
        var val = form[item.name].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        form[item.name].value = val;
        // see if it matches the regex
        valid = item.re.test(val);
        if (valid && item.isDate) {
            matches = val.match(item.re);
            month = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
            day = parseInt(matches[2], 10);
            year = parseInt(matches[3], 10);
            if (month <= 0 || month > 12 || 
                day <= 0 || day >= 31 || 
                year < 1900 || year > 2020) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            incomplete = true;
            msg += item.tag + '\n\t';
        } else {
            if (item.min && item.max) {
                // clear out non-numeric chars
                val = val.replace(/[,\$\s]/g, "");
                // convert to a number
                num = parseInt(val, 10);
                // compare to min and max
                if (num < item.min || num > item.max) {
                    incomplete = true;
                    msg += item.tag + " (must be between " + item.min + " and " + item.max + ")\n\t";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (incomplete) {
        msg += '\nOK   submit incomplete form';
        msg += '\nCANCEL  return to the form';
        return(confirm(msg));
    }
    return(true);
}
```

​
Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GChEP/

Comment: jfriend you are awesome. It is 2 am here, but I am going to go try this, might take me a while, lol!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do would be to use classes to know what kind of validation you need for a given `input`. Also, you can use the `title` attribute to have a more human-friendly representiation of the `input`.

Your HTML would then look like:

```
<form name="loanform" action="processform.htm" method="get" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    First Name (text only): <input class="validate-text" title="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="15"><br>
    Last Name (text only): <input class="validate-text" title="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="15"><br>
    Birth Date (format dd/mm/yyyy): <input class="validate-date" title="Birth Date" type="text" name="birthdate"  maxlength="8"><br>
    Loan Amount (US dollars, numeric only): <input class="validate-number" title="Loan Amount" type="text" name="loanamount"  maxlength="6" ><br>
    Years (numeric only): <input class="validate-number" title="Years" type="text" name="years"  maxlength="2"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="reset" value="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And your JavaScript function (regular expressions seem to be the best way to go):

```
function validate(f) {
  var message=new Array(); //will contain the fields that are misfilled
  var reText=new RegExp("^[a-z \-'\.]+$", "i"); //a RegExp to match names: only letters, "-", "'" and "." allowed
  var reDate=new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$"); //a RegExp to match a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy
  var reNumber=new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); //a RegExp to match a number
  for(var e in f.elements) { //loop on every input of the form
    var test=null; //set or reset the RegExp to use for the current input
    var input=f.elements[e]; //assign the input to a var (easier to type, not needed)
    if(!input.className) //if this input doesn't have any class declared
      continue; //then we skip the rest of the loop to keep going with the next input
    var classes=input.className.split(" "); //maybe the input has several classes, so we split them in a "classes" array
    for(var c in classes) { //we loop on every class of the current input
      switch(classes[c]) { //and we test if the current class of the current input is one of the classes we're interested in
        case "validate-text": //if it is a text
          test=reText; //the variable "test" will contain the RegExp we want to use
          break;
        case "validate-date": //same for a date
          test=reDate;
          break;
        case "validate-number": //and same for a number
          test=reNumber;
          break;
        default: //if the class is not something we want, nothing to do
          break;
      } //end switch
    } //end classes loop
    //here test is either null (no "validate-something" class found for the current input), or it contains the RegExp telling us the kind of input we must validate.
    if(test!=null && !input.value.match(test)) { //if it is not null and if the input's value does not match the RegExp
      message.push(input.title); //we add the field to the "message" array
    }
  } //end input loop
  if(message.length>0) { //if the arary is not empty, we display a confirm box
    return confirm("Please correctly fill the following field(s), or click OK to send an incomplete form:\n"+message.join("\n"));
  }
  //otherwise, the form is correctly filled, we return true to submit the form
  return true;
}
```